# Access forbidden to website after scp transfer

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, gulp, scp

I used [scp2](https://www.npmjs.org/package/scp2) to tranfer a folder from windows to ubuntu.
I executed the scp2 process as part of a gulp execution.
My project was successfuly transfered to the server but when I tried to navigate to the site from the browser I encountered a `403 Forbidden` message.

The problem is that the scp2 process didn't grant permissions to the newly created folder and files.
When I execute the following lines on the server it's work fine:

```
find ProjFolder -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;    
find ProjFolder -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

My question is: how can I transfer my project from my local machine to the server without the need to repeatedly write the permission orders?

Answer (score 0):

To preserve permissions try to use rsync, it has a lot more benefits besides keeping ownership, permissions and incremental copies:

```
rsync -av source 192.0.2.1:/dest/ination
```

EDIT [according to comments]:

This works well for transferring between 2 Linux systems but doesn't seem to work for Windows -> Linux transfer. Apparently PuTTY seems to work best for transfers involving Windows on one side and Linux on another

Comment: I tried using rsync combined with gulp for no end.
I ended up using PuTTY's pscp and ran it with [gulp-run](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-run).

Comment: That's strange. Thanks for mentioning. I'm not a Windows user and rsync has always worked while transferring between two linux systems. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: now when I think of it, a lot of my friends who are Windows users use PuTTY. This is probably one of the reasons.